# How can one estimate distance covered while spot-swimming?

Tags: equipment, training, strategy, swimming

I’ve been finding it difficult to track my progress while swimming with a swimming cord. Is there a swim watch or tracker that can provide an estimate of the distance covered while training like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSD swim was the product category I was looking for.

https://nsdspinner.com/products/nsd-swim-trainer-system-sw01

https://youtu.be/jZflDlWQigM?t=29

[image]

It is capable of calculating the force exerted and the distance during a swim.

Answer (score 5):

I've not used it, but the FINIS Swimsense watch claims to count strokes (and laps and distance and...) which then can be uploaded to a computer.  There are also on-finger counters, although those might be more applicable to lab counting and not your application unless you really like twitching your fingers...

Timed swimming on the cord, compared with known times for measured distances free swimming, might get you an estimate.

Personally, I find that swimming on a cord has a very different effort-to-stroke ratio than regular lap swims - it is more like using paddles in terms of what my shoulders feel.

Comment: I think the only effective way of estimating the distance in this case would be to either measure the tension on the cord or thru the micro-difference in your distance from the wall. Strokes and finger counters won't be as effective. 

We have a small 10m pool here and I am always swimming with the cord. I have done 1 km in 30 mins and so I swim for 30 mins. But one can't really track one's PROGRESS without a measurement of distance.